# cx, cy vs transform in svg and D3, what is the difference?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I m working on a [forced layout](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout) and couldnT figure out why trying to move the nodes via cx, cy does not work.

```
// This works    
node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.

//This doesn't
    node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
                    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
```

The nodes are in a svg `g` element actually, might that be why?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The `cx` and `cy` attributes work for `circle` elements only. For `g` elements, use `transform`.

Some more explanation: the element-specific attributes `cx`, `cy`, `x`, `y`, etc. position the element *within* the coordinate system. The `transform` attribute *repositions the coordinate system*. For elements that do not have specific position attributes, this is the only way of positioning.

Comment: So, why are we limited to positioning only circles within the coordinate system?
Surely there must be a way to do this for other elements too. Like a rectangle?

Comment: Yes, there are equivalent attributes for other shapes.